# How can I set authorization token in Vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt, vue-router

I am using JWT authorization in laravel 5.2 with Vue Js.
I have separate folders for client side and server side. I logged in application with following code:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: null,
      password: null,
      error: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login () {
      var app = this
      this.$auth.login({
        params: {
          email: app.email,
          password: app.password
        },
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(this.$auth.token())
          this.$auth.user(response.data.user)
        },
        error: function () {},
        rememberMe: false,
        redirect: '/',
        fetchUser: true
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Server side code:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'error' => 'invalid.credentials',
                    'msg' => 'Invalid Credentials.'
                ], 400);
        }
        return response([
                'status' => 'success'
            ])
            ->header('Authorization', $token);
    }
```

After that it should get user info also due to `fetchUser: true`.
At login time I got an authorization code but when it requests fetch user call it doesn't have Authorization token in header and it generates an error:

> Token_not_provided

I am new to Vue.js.